# Library: Java influxdb client. - influx HTTP status code: 401; Message: Unauthorized access

Tags: influxdb, http-status-code-401, unauthorized, flux-influxdb

Java client library: finfluxdb client
https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-java

```
Builder builder = InfluxDBClientOptions.builder();
builder.url(serverUrl);
if (!token.isEmpty()) {
 builder.authenticateToken(token.toCharArray()); // 1.
} else {
 builder.authenticate(username, password.toCharArray()); // 2.
}
builder.bucket(bucketName);
builder.org(organization);
InfluxDBClientOptions options = builder.build();
```

1. the connection via builder.authenticateToken(token.toCharArray()); works.
2. If the connection is made via builder.authenticate(username, password.toCharArray()); --> error message   influx HTTP status code: 401; message: Unauthorized access

I have tried to find an answer through google in the expectation of a solution